# Howto join ssl_access_log and access_log?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, logging, log-files, mod-ssl

Recently I discovered in my /var/log/httpd files called ssl_access_log and ssl_error_log. Now I always looked and scanned the regular access_log and error_log. Questions are?

1. Do ssl_error_log and ssl_access_log are included in the access_log and error_log ?
2. How do I join the ssl_access_log and access_log to be together so I won't need to check them both ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the same file name in the log generation directive.